placeholder-shown pseudo class seems not to work on safari
When I use :not(::placeholder-shown),  :NOT seems to be not working in safari browsers.
If you are not on safari: Below i added a way to use the safari browser with playwright so you can test it yourself.
app.js
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Form Validation Example</title>
  <style>
    input:not(:placeholder-shown):invalid {
      border-color: crimson;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
    <input type="email" placeholder="" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>`

Use Playwright to imitate Safari:
const { webkit } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  const browser = await webkit.launch({ headless: false }); // Launch Safari in non-headless mode
  const context = await browser.newContext(); // Create a new browser context
  const page = await context.newPage(); // Open a new page

  // Set HTML content
  const content = `<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Form Validation Example</title>
  <style>
    input:not(:placeholder-shown):invalid {
      border-color: crimson;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
    <input type="email" placeholder="" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>`;

  await page.setContent(content); // Load the HTML content in the page
})();


npm init -y
npm install playwright
node app.js



I got it fixed by using a non empty placeholder. Instead of using placeholder="", I use placeholder=" "
